# add1 function from scheme to R5RS

Tags: scheme, racket, r5rs

I've written some code but it's not working because the `add1` function I used in Scheme is not working with R5RS. What can replace `add1` in R5RS?

Comment: R5RS **is** Scheme.  The S is for Scheme. Do you mean the add1 from Racket?

Answer (score 6):

The procedure `add1` is very simple, you can implement it yourself:

```
(define (add1 x)
  (+ x 1))
```

Comment: Or you can just use `(+ 1 x)` and save one keystroke.

Answer (score 0):

late answer but an alternative is *(making use of lambdas)*..

```
(define add1 
    (lambda (x)
        (+ x 1)))
```

Comment: I cannot imagine any Scheme implementation where the two forms would be treated differently at all, assuming we are talking about the implementation's default implementation of `define`. Thus, your answer is exactly equivalent to Óscar's answer, so it's not an alternative per se.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I meant alternate way of writing. Arguably useless but who doesn't want to show off their newfound Scheme skills.

Comment: Here's a showoff answer for you (it macro-expands to exactly the same thing, but looks cooler; requires [SRFI 26](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-26/srfi-26.html)): `(define add1 (cut + <> 1))` :-D