# In Lisp is the function `1+` just syntactic sugar?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I just started learning Lisp. One of the first concepts to grasp seems to be the prefix notation (i.e. instead of writing "1 + 2", write "+ 1 2"). So I am trying to work out why the `1+` function exists.

What is the reason to prefer `(+ 1 2)` or `(1+ 2)`?

Is it just syntactic sugar? Is it for code optimisation? Is it for readability?

Perhaps there are more complex function call examples that show why the `1+` function exists. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do remember that part of Common Lisp was standardizing what many implementations already had.  So, if many implementations already had a **1+** function, that could have been enough to include it.  [Rainer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30933000/1281433) quotes CLtL2 on *which* implementations had it (MacLisp and Lisp Machine Lisp).  But why would those implementations have had it in the first place?  It's useful in loops, e.g.,

```
(do ((x 0 (1+ x)))
    ((= x 10))
  ; ...
  )
```

That's a place where **(+ x 1)** would have been fine, too.  But there are lots of cases where it's handy to call that kind of function indirectly, and it's easier to **(mapcar '1+ …)** than to **(mapcar (lambda (x) (+ 1 x)) …)**.

But that's really about it.  Adding one (or subtracting one;  there's **1-** as well) to something is just such a common operation that it's handy to have a function to do it.  If there's hardware support, it might be something the implementation can optimize, too.  (Although [the documentation](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_1pl_1_.htm) does note that "implementors are encouraged to make the performance of [(1+ number) and (+ 1 number)] be the same.")  Since these functions are available and widely used, they're a very good way to indicate the intent.  E.g., you could make a typo and write **(+ 1 x)** when you meant to write **(+ 2 x)**, but it's much less likely that you wanted to add two if you actually wrote **(1+ x)**.  These functions are idiomatic in Common Lisp (e.g., see [How do I increment or decrement a number in Common Lisp?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3736094/1281433)).  Emacs Lisp also [includes 1+ and 1-](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Arithmetic-Operations.html).

The language wouldn't suffer greatly if it weren't there, but it would be reimplemented many times by many different people.  For instance, Racket implements [add1](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._add1%29%29) and [sub1](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._sub1%29%29). (Also, see [add1 function from scheme to R5RS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292094/add1-function-from-scheme-to-r5rs).)

Comment: Thank you, very helpful and informative. I had not thought about the standardization part before.

Answer (score 12):

Common Lisp the Language:

> These are included primarily for compatibility with MacLisp and Lisp Machine Lisp. Some programmers prefer always to write (+ x 1) and (- x 1) instead of (1+ x) and (1- x).

Actually this goes back to the early Lisp. Lisp 1.5 from 1962 has it already. There the functions were called `ADD1` and `SUB1`.